# How to require that a protocol can only be adopted by a specific class

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I want this protocol:

```
protocol AddsMoreCommands {
     /* ... */
}
```

only to be adopted by classes that inherit from the class `UIViewController`. [This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) tells me I can specify that it is only adopted by a class (as opposed to a struct) by writing

```
protocol AddsMoreCommands: class {
}
```

but I cannot see how to require that it is only adopted by a particular class. [That page later](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) talks about adding `where` clauses to protocol extensions to check conformance but I cannot see how to adapt that either.

```
extension AddsMoreCommands where /* what */ {
}
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
protocol AddsMoreCommands: class {
    // Code
}

extension AddsMoreCommands where Self: UIViewController {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: I so nearly had it... I wrote `self` instead of `Self` :-( Thank you very much, that works fine!

Comment: For me, this causes some syntactic strangeness when I use this in conjunction with casting.

Comment: This won't work if you need to include a property in the protocol, as extensions cannot contain stored properties.

Comment: It can have stored propertied you only need to use this: objc_getAssociatedObject(self,
                &KeyName) as? PropertyType

Comment: This also requires casting when a let/var declaration has type `AddsMoreCommands` but a method you pass it to expects a `UIViewController`

Comment: The docs changed to using `AnyObject` instead of `class` -> https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID281. But both versions are behaving the same for now without deprecation warnings.

Comment: Is it just a fact of Swift syntax that you cannot add overrides in to these? E.g., `override var prefersStatusBarHidden`?

Answer (score 92):

This can also be achieved without an extension:

```
protocol AddsMoreCommands: UIViewController {
    // code
}
```

Which is exactly the same as:

```
protocol AddsMoreCommands where Self: UIViewController {
   // code
}
```

I usually use the first option, IIRC I read a while ago on the Swift docs that that is the recomended way when the constraint is `Self`, if is other constraint such as [associate types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html) is when `where` can be used.

Notice that since `UIViewController` is a `class` too, this protocol can be implemented for weak properties such as delegates.

**EDITED 2021/01/05**: Previous posted solution had a warning, I have removed it and use this one which does not produce any warning.

Comment: How coincidental is it that I clicked on a two year old question and find a perfect solution posted one hour ago 

Comment: Xcode 9.1 is now giving me a warning about this saying:

Redundant layout constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject'.

Layout constraint constraint 'Self' : 'AnyObject' implied here.

Changing my code to the format of the accepted answer seems to be more gooder.

Comment: As of Xcode 9.1 class-only protocols now use `AnyObject` instead of `class`.  `protocol AddsMoreCommands: AnyObject where Self: UIViewController {  // code }`

Comment: @dodgio still getting same warning using `AnyObject`

Comment: Yes, the warning still shows. Here's the [Swift bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6265) for it. The compiler is complaining (cryptically) that the code is specifying "AnyObject" twice on the protocol. The bug lists why that's a bad warning.

Comment: I'm using `protocol Foo where Self: Bar`, any reason why you aren't using this pattern?

Comment: Protocols can be adopted by struct, enum and classes. But for example, if your protocol is a DataSource or Delegate, it needs to be _weak_ to avoid a retain circle, and in order to make the property _weak_ you need to use `: class`. When using `: class` your protocol can be implemented JUST on classes.
In this case I used `: class` since the accepted answer is using it.

Comment: @rgkobashi there's no need to use `class` since you're already restricting conformance to `UIViewController` sub_classes_. `protocol RatingControllerDelegate where Self: UIViewController` compiles just fine and produces no warnings in Xcode9.1+.

Comment: @DávidPásztor you are right, however if you want to use it on a structural pattern such as delegation, to be able to make the property weak it is necessary to add ´class´ explicitly :)

Comment: Is this saying that anything that AddsMoreCommands MUST be a UIViewController, or that all the requirements of that protocol only have to be implemented by UIViewControllers? i.e. if you have var addsMore: AddsMoreCommands, can the compiler assume that it is dealing with a UIViewController that implements that protocol. My experience says the compiler can't do that.

Comment: @Giles I am not sure what you mean with the first question but this is more like the second one. All the requirements of this protocol MUST be implemented by UIViewControllers. If you have addsMore: AddsMoreCommands the compiler cannot assume that it is dealing with a UIViewController, that is one of the good things about POP, you remove those kind of restrictions. However the compiler will know when you are trying to implement AddsMoreCommands on a non-UIViewController.

Answer (score 51):

Because of an issue in the previous answer I ended up with this declaration:

```
protocol AddsMoreCommands where Self : UIViewController { 
    // protocol stuff here  
}
```

no warnings in Xcode 9.1

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the issue with this over the solution above   (which is generating a warning in Xcode 9.1 and upwards), is that you can't declare the delegate as weak?

Comment: Also, when I use this solution with Swift 4.1, I need to cast properties of the `AddsMoreCommands` to `UIViewController` which I wanted to avoid...

Comment: To avoid the type cast, you could do this: `typealias AddsMoreCommandsViewController = UIViewController & AddsMoreCommands`

Answer (score 39):

Now in **Swift 5** you can achieve this by:

```
protocol AddsMoreCommands: UIViewController {
     /* ... */
}
```

Quite handy.

Comment: What is the difference between these two?

extension AddsMoreCommands where Self: UIViewController {
    // Code
}

AND

protocol AddsMoreCommands: UIViewController {
     /* ... */
}

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I think you meant `protocol` instead of `extension`, if that is the case, someone already [answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57001123/8483739)