# Difference when declaring swift protocol using inheritance from another protocol or using where Self

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I still don't understand what is the difference when declaring a Swift protocol using inheritance:

```
protocol SubProtocol: SuperProtocol { ... }
```

or using `where Self`

```
protocol SubProtocol where Self: SuperProtocol { ... }
```

By doing this on these two ways the results are exactly the same, both options compile fine, and it works, `SubProtocol` will have the same stuff than `SuperProtocol` has. So what is the difference?

The only difference I can see is the semantic, one is more clear than the other (see example below). But this is my point of view and I would like to know if someone else thinks the same, or perhaps I am miss-understanding the whole thing.

**Example:**

```
protocol Progressable {
    var isInProgress: Bool { get }
}

protocol Downloadable: Progressable {
    func download()
}

protocol ProgressReporting where Self: Progressable {
    func reportProgress() -> Bool
}
```

For me, `Downloadable` makes sense it inherits from `Progressable`, every download is progressable, so that is fine.

But `ProgressReporting` not necessary needs to inherit from `Progressable`, for me it would make more sense to constraint it by using where, this way the reader can know that whoever implements it, will need to conform to `Progressable` too (see the comments on the code below), here is when I think the semantic is different.

```
class MyClassA: Downloadable {
    var isInProgress: Bool { return true }
    func download() {}

    func foo() {
        /*
         I have access to `self.isInProgress` because this class conforms `Downloadable`
         which inherits from `Progressable`, so this makes sense
         */
        _ = self.isInProgress
    }
}

class MyClassB: ProgressReporting {
    var isInProgress: Bool { return true }
    func reportProgress() {}

    func foo() {
        /*
         I have access to `self.isInProgress` but according to `ProgressReporting` definition,
         this class should be `Progressable` which is not, at least not explicitely
         */
        _ = self.isInProgress
    }
}
```

I would apreciate if someone can explain me what are the differences

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought perhaps the `where` approach imposes requirements on `Self`, but without setting up the type relationship that anything that conforms to `SubProtocol` will also also transitively conform to `SuperProtocol` (as is the case with `Hashable`/`Equatable`, for example). But that's not the case, they both work the same in this manner, too: https://repl.it/@alexandermomchilov/Protocols-colon-vs-Self-requirment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking about Swift5, there is no difference between the two forms, see [Swift 5 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2):

> Protocols can now constrain their conforming types to those that subclass a given class. Two equivalent forms are supported:
>
> ```
> protocol MyView: UIView { /*...*/ }
> protocol MyView where Self: UIView { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> Swift 4.2 accepted the second form, but it wasn’t fully implemented and could sometimes crash at compile time or runtime. (SR-5581) (38077232)

Comment: awesome! This is what I was looking for! Thanks!