# How to make protocol conformed by only required classes?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift-protocols

I'm trying to achieve type constraint on protocols. In my current project I have a following base controller. I examined [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133887/how-to-require-that-a-protocol-can-only-be-adopted-by-a-specific-class) too but I don't understand why it isn't working.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
}
```

I declared two protocol based on my requirements.

```
protocol A: AnyObject {
    func execute()
}

extension A {
    func execute() {
        print("Execute")
    }
}

protocol B {
    func confirm()
}

extension B where Self: BaseViewController & A {
    func confirm() {
        
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to prevent all classes which doesn't conform protocol A and `BaseViewController` also can't conform protocol B also.

However, when I try to conform `protocol B` in another `UIViewController` which doesn't conform `protocol A` there is no error.

```
class AnotherVC: UIViewController {
}

extension AnotherVC: B {
    func confirm() {
    }
}
```

How can I restrict other view controllers to conform `protocol B` if they don't conform `protocol A` and inherit from `BaseViewController`

Comment: it’s working because AnotheVC is still a subclass of UIViewController, and BaseViewController is also subclass of UIViewController. So, basically BaseViewController have a IS-A relationship to UIViewController.

Comment: I see your point but it needs to be also conform A protocol because of & ? @TusharSharma

Comment: protocol A have IS-A relationship with AnyObject. So, it basically means any class type can implement that protocol (reference types). When you say `extension AnotherVC: B`  and B has a constraint that `self` should be `UIViewController & Class`. Which is exactly what you have, `AnotherVC` is a class and also subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Yes, you are right now I understand. When I constraint Self: BaseViewController & A I supposed to `AnotherVC` must conform to protocol B. Is there any way to achieve what I need? @TusharSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if below code is what you need, do let me know if that’s what you were looking for, else I will be happy to remove my answer.

```
protocol A:BaseViewController  {
    func execute()
}

protocol B:A {
    func confirm()
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    
}

class AnotherVC: B {
   
}
```

In above code compiler will give error saying-:

> 'A' requires that 'AnotherVC' inherit from ‘BaseViewController'

Once you inherit `AnotherVC` from `BaseViewController`, it will give another error saying-:

> Type 'AnotherVC' does not conform to protocol ‘A'

Once you confirm the implementations errors will be resolved-:

```
class AnotherVC:BaseViewController, B {
    func confirm() {
        
    }
    
    func execute() {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort and comment, but what I'd like to achieve is that for example I have two protocol A and B. I need to create a rule that if a class doesn't conform protocol A also can't conform protocol B.

Comment: @atalayasa I guess that’s what code does, when I implement AnotherVC with B, compiler complains that AnotherVC does not confirm BaseViewController and protocol A. Once we provide both rules only then it works. Or is it something else I missed.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I thought so complicated now it's working as I wished :)